# Security warning: Untrusted VPN Server Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, vpn, cisco

I am new to ssl vpn and i am currently facing some issue with failure try to identify the source of the following issue:

When i connect to test.dyndns.org using my cisco anyconnect client, it gave me the following issue, that is shown in the image in this link:  https://supportforums.cisco.com/sites/default/files/legacy/9/3/7/112739-Certificate%20Error%20Message.jpg

Can any one help me in solving it?

Answer (score -1):

You're using an untrusted certificate (one not signed by a trusted certificate authority).  You can usually disable this error popping up by overriding a "strict enforcement" policy, but you really wouldn't want to as it undermines the integrity of the VPN Tunnel's security.

Assuming you're using this with the intent to trust the VPN that you're using you really should use a trusted TLS/SSL certificate.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but can you tell me where or in which program i have to disable it, you mean in profile editor , and how ? i am really new in this, however i am planing to study more about it .. can you guide me please